# Compiling ECL 11.1.1 on Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion)

Tags: macos, segmentation-fault, common-lisp, osx-lion, ecl

I have been trying to build ECL under OS X 10.7 and I have been
running into trouble. When I try building it I end up getting a
segfault on the ecl_min stage.

I configure with the following line:

```
./configure --build=x86_64 --target=x86_64 --prefix=`pwd`/install_ecl
CC=/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

And the compile fails with:

```
if [ -f CROSS-COMPILER ]; then \
    ./CROSS-COMPILER compile; \
else \
    ECLDIR=`pwd`/ ./ecl_min compile; \
fi
/bin/sh: line 1: 17433 Segmentation fault: 11  ECLDIR=`pwd`/ ./ecl_min compile
```

I have tried building gmp and boehm-gc externally and not using the
included ones, but unfortunately it ended up with the same results. I
have also tried the default llvm-gcc without much luck either.

Has anyone been able to compile ECL under Lion, and if so, what configure options / patches did you need to apply.

Update:
I was able to compile thanks to the accepted answer below. Here is the scripts that I used (Note: This is from a fresh git clone of ECL):

```
#!/bin/sh

ECL_INSTALLDIR="`pwd`/install_ecl"
mkdir -p $ECL_INSTALLDIR

./configure\
     --prefix=$ECL_INSTALLDIR\
     --enable-boehm\
     --enable-unicode=no\
     CC=/Developer/usr/bin/gcc\
     CXX=/Developer/usr/bin/g++\
     CFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
     LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS"

make && make install
```

Comment: I shall be trying it out shortly. I'll update it with my results.

Comment: The enable/disabling of unicode does not affect whether it compiles or not. I have it disabled since my pet project does not use unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.lisp.ecl.general/) describes the two causes of the problem (an issue with the compiler, and an issue with garbage collector compatibility), and offers a temporary solution until the issue itself is fixed. The instructions come down to:

1. Download a new build of the Boehm-Weiser garbage collector library, apply a patch (you can get a link to download both the library and the patch from that page as well), and install it somewhere
2. Configure ECL with these extra options:

```
    --enable-boehm=system
    CPPFLAGS=-I/location/for/library/include
    LDFLAGS=-L/location/for/library/lib
```

Where `/location/for/library` is the prefix you used to install the garbage collector.

And then it should build properly.

I also found [this MacPorts ticket](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/30489) which seems to be tracking this issue; check there for future updates to see if it will be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been fixed in git/CVS. As explained above, the cause for the miscompilation was the version of our garbage collector: we shipped the last one available: 7.1, but this does not work with OS X Lion. ECL now ships with two versions (7.1 and 7.2-cvs), using the newest one in OS X Lion. In other words, ECL from git/CVS (http://ecls.sourceforge.net/download.html) should compile and run out of the box.

Comment: Updated the main question to reflect the changes.